# Reference sibling lookup items in a Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2016

I have a basic data structure built up using SharePoint lists where the child list has a lookup column pointing to the parent list.  There is always exactly one instance of each sibling item under a parent item.  Here is the structure:

```
// ParentList
//  - Sibling1 
//  - Sibling2
//  - Sibling3
```

What I am trying to do is trigger a designer workflow on the creation of an item in Sibling3.  This workflow sends a summary email containing information from the ParentList and also from each of the Sibling lists.

I cannot find a way to successfully reference the sibling list item.  When I set up the "Lookup for String" dialog options in Designer I set:

```
// Data source = Sibling1
// Field from source = MyFieldNameInSibling1
// Return field as = usually "Formatted Currency", but depends on the field above
// Find the List Item - Field = MyLookupToParentInSibling1
// Find the List Item - Value = function lookup, details on next three lines
//    - DataSource = CurrentItem
//    - Field from source = MyLookupToParentInSibling3
//    - Return field as = Only available options are "As String" and "Lookup Value (as Text)"
```

No matter what I set to define the "Find the List Item - Value" I cannot get the workflow to ever locate the sibling list item, so none of the values are included in the email.

Has anyone successfully referenced a sibling list item in a designer workflow?  Can you provide details on the difference between what I am doing and what you did?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the answer myself.  There was no problem in the actual logic of the structure above.  The reason it couldn't locate the sibling lists was because the lookup column in Sibling3 was defined to lookup by Id and all the other lists were defined to lookup by Title.  As soon as I redefined the Sibling3 lookup column to lookup by Title, everything started working.

Hopefully this helps someone in future.  ... God, I feel stupid...